# replacing multiple matches in preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-replace-callback

I have a string which reads foo_bar_one, what I am trying to achieve is

foo_Bar_One, using this regex `/(?<=_)./` I tried to implement a `preg_replace_callback` but it is not working as supposed else I have misunderstood the functionality of the function.

this is my method

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '/(?<=_)./',
    function ($matches) {
        return strtoupper($matches[0]);
    },
    $model_name
);
```

It is matching and converting to Caps but when does it return? Does it not replace the it in the actual search text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the return values of the [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

> preg_replace_callback() returns an array if the subject parameter is
>   an array, or a string otherwise. On errors the return value is NULL
>
> If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, otherwise
>   subject will be returned unchanged.

So you could capture what is being returned like:

```
$model_name = "foo_bar_one";
$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(?<=_)./',
    function ($matches) {
        return strtoupper($matches[0]);
    },
    $model_name
);

echo $result;
```

That will give you

> foo_Bar_One

Comment: Oh, I really missed that point, I thought I will update the search string. Thanks for pointing that out.